# how to break it into function

Tags: php, function

I have some 'else if' cases in a page. Now I want to make only a single function so that code length may be shorten.

```
elseif ($domain == 1 && $case == 2) {
$result = array();
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        $result[] = $data;
    }

    foreach ($result as $index) {
        foreach ($index as $value) {
            $resultArr[] = explode('      ', $value[0]);
        }
    }
    $valuesArr = array();
  //////********Below code is repeated in this page **************///////

    $sql = "INSERT INTO LEAD_TMP_UPLOAD (LEAD_SOURCE , LAST_NAME , EMAIL , MOBILE , IVR_NUMBER , RECORDING_URL , COUNTRY , LEAD_STATUS , DEAD_REASON , PROJECT_NAME
 , CUSTOMER_QUERY , DESCRIPTION , LEAD_OWNER , FOLLOW_UP_DATE , CITY_INTERESTED_IN , LOCALITY , UPLOAD_DATE , UPLOAD_BY_ID , REFERED_BY
, REFERED_LEAD_ID , SUB_BROKER_DETAIL , BUDGET , USER_ENQUIRY_TIME , LEAD_TYPE , INSERT_STATUS , PROCESSING_STATUS , UPDATED_AT , LEAD_STAGE ) values ";
        foreach ($resultArr as $data) {

            $lead_source = "99Acres";
        $name = trim(strip_tags(str_replace('Name  :  ', '', $data[0]))) ;
        $emailId = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Email  :  ', 'Verified'), '', $data[1])));
        $contactNo = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Phone number   :  ', '     Verified'), '', $data[2])));
        $ivr_no = "";   //null
        $recording_url = "";        //null
        $country = "";
        $lead_status = "New";
        $dead_reason = "";      //null
        $project_name = trim(strip_tags($value[2]));;
        $customer_query = " ";
        $description = " ";
        $lead_owner = "sachin.sharma";
        $follow_up_date = date('Y-F-j h:i:s A');          //current date
        $city_interested_in = "";
        $locality = "";
        $upload_date = date('Y-F-j h:i:s A');           //current date
        $upload_by_id = 2;
        $reffered_by = 0;
        $reffered_lead_id = 0;
        $sub_broker_detail = 0;
        $budget =   "";                            //max range
        $user_enquiry_time =  "";                      //mailbox time
        $lead_type = "";
        $insert_status = "";
        $processing_status = "";
        $updated_at = "";
        $lead_stage = "cold";

     $valuesArr[] .= "('$lead_source', '$name', '$emailId', '$contactNo', '$ivr_no', '$recording_url', '$country', '$lead_status', '$dead_reason', '$project_name ', '$customer_query', '$description', '$lead_owner', '$follow_up_date', '$city_interested_in', '$locality', '$upload_date', '$upload_by_id', '$reffered_by', '$reffered_lead_id', '$sub_broker_detail' , '$budget' , '$user_enquiry_time', '$lead_type', '$insert_status', '$processing_status', '$updated_at', '$lead_stage')";
        }
    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    echo $sql;

//////********Till Here, code is repeated in this page **************///////
}
```

please tell my how can i break above code into another function so that I can save my code length from same code repetition.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit as I am new into this.

Comment: @Gunaseelan I have mentioned in comments //////********Below code is repeated in this page **************/////// this code part is repeating in my php page.therefore for shorten the code I want to make a function. Did I make my point clear?

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
elseif ($domain == 1 && $case == 2) {
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {
    $result[] = $data;
}

foreach ($result as $index) {
    foreach ($index as $value) {
        $resultArr[] = explode('      ', $value[0]);
    }
}
$valuesArr = array();

_insert($resultArr);

}

function _insert($resultArr){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO LEAD_TMP_UPLOAD (LEAD_SOURCE , LAST_NAME , EMAIL , MOBILE ,         IVR_NUMBER ,    RECORDING_URL , COUNTRY , LEAD_STATUS , DEAD_REASON , PROJECT_NAME
    ,         CUSTOMER_QUERY , DESCRIPTION , LEAD_OWNER , FOLLOW_UP_DATE , CITY_INTERESTED_IN , LOCALITY ,   UPLOAD_DATE , UPLOAD_BY_ID , REFERED_BY
    , REFERED_LEAD_ID , SUB_BROKER_DETAIL , BUDGET , USER_ENQUIRY_TIME , LEAD_TYPE , INSERT_STATUS ,      PROCESSING_STATUS , UPDATED_AT , LEAD_STAGE ) values ";
    foreach ($resultArr as $data) {

        $lead_source = "99Acres";
    $name = trim(strip_tags(str_replace('Name  :  ', '', $data[0]))) ;
    $emailId = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Email  :  ', 'Verified'), '', $data[1])));
    $contactNo = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array('Phone number   :  ', '     Verified'), '',     $data[2])));
    $ivr_no = "";   //null
    $recording_url = "";        //null
    $country = "";
    $lead_status = "New";
    $dead_reason = "";      //null
    $project_name = trim(strip_tags($value[2]));;
    $customer_query = " ";
    $description = " ";
    $lead_owner = "sachin.sharma";
    $follow_up_date = date('Y-F-j h:i:s A');          //current date
    $city_interested_in = "";
    $locality = "";
    $upload_date = date('Y-F-j h:i:s A');           //current date
    $upload_by_id = 2;
    $reffered_by = 0;
    $reffered_lead_id = 0;
    $sub_broker_detail = 0;
    $budget =   "";                            //max range
    $user_enquiry_time =  "";                      //mailbox time
    $lead_type = "";
    $insert_status = "";
    $processing_status = "";
    $updated_at = "";
    $lead_stage = "cold";

    $valuesArr[] .= "('$lead_source', '$name', '$emailId', '$contactNo', '$ivr_no', '$recording_url', '$country', '$lead_status', '$dead_reason', '$project_name ', '$customer_query', '$description', '$lead_owner', '$follow_up_date', '$city_interested_in', '$locality', '$upload_date', '$upload_by_id', '$reffered_by', '$reffered_lead_id', '$sub_broker_detail' , '$budget' , '$user_enquiry_time', '$lead_type', '$insert_status', '$processing_status', '$updated_at', '$lead_stage')";
    }
    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    echo $sql;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but, what if I want to change $data[0],$data[1] parameters in every function calling? which is data coming into $name,$email variables.

Comment: could you please help me to move further?